# how to create binary which can be installed in all iphones without creating App Store or Ad Hoc?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

i want to create an application which will not launch in AppStore but all my clients can install my application in their devices. the problem is that i do not have all my clients devices `UDID`. how they can insert my application because i can't create Ad Hoc since i do not have all my clients UDID and i do not want to create an App Store binary.

Please tell me this is possible or not.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can turn your app into a web app, then yes you can do it.

But assuming you are talking about a native iOS app, and you don't want to require clients to jailbreak their phones, then no, Apple have a single distribution channel and that's the App Store.

If your clients are 'internal' clients, ie you want to distribute within your own organisation, then the enterprise program is an option for you;

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

If your clients are large, and want to buy in volume and then re-distribute internally, another option may be the custom B2B program;

http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

Answer (score 4):

Use InHouse distribution, see

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

and

http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/apps/in-house/

In short, you'll need an Enterprise account. With it, you can create inhouse-distributions that work the same as ad-hoc (i.e. you can distribute them directly or via Over-the-air), except that you don't need to specify UDIDs.

However, since this is a major security "flaw" you have to make sure that everyone who downloads/gets this app is properly authenticated one way or another.

**Important:** If your clients are not members or subcompanies of your company, I'd check the legal status of using InHouse distribution for this. I'm not sure myself.